# Java KeyPressed for all keys

Tags: java, input, awt, keypress, stringreader

In java I'm making an application that, when activated (if wantCommand = true), it will read what ever key you press it reads and adds it to a string, and then using Java.awt.Graphics, it draws the string to the screen... Can someone help me with the code to getting the String to what you type (and possibly a deleting also in case you messed up what you were typing)
Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class slashCommand {
    public static boolean wantCommand = false;
    public static String commandLine = "kill";
    public static String getText () {
        //get the string in a for loop or something maybe
        return commandLine;
    }
    public static void render(Graphics g) {
        if (wantCommand) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 130));
            g.fillRect(Inventory.inv_bag[0].x - 100, Inventory.inv_bag[0].y + 116, Component.size.width, 10);
            g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));
            g.drawString("/ " + commandLine, Inventory.inv_bag[0].x - 69, Inventory.inv_bag[0].y + 125);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a long way to go. You need:

- Most importantly a GUI, preferably Swing and not AWT, so that your key presses and String drawing have an application to interact with and display data from.
- A KeyListener attached to a component that has focus. Note that I don't think that Key Bindings would work well for this.
- An JPanel with an overridden `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

Comment: I already have the first and last options, they are in a different class. this is just an attached class to a game i already have.

Comment: @BryceHahn: without more context and code, it will be hard to figure out what is wrong. If you have a large code base, most won't have the time to review it, but you might want to consider creating and posting a [minimal, compilable, runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run, test, and modify, and that shows us your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register a keyPressed event listener to the GUI; the event tells which key got pressed which you can pass around

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)                                
{                                    
   System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar());
}
```